# Writing Timestamp into CSV then Appending values

Tags: matlab, csv, append

I have timestamps in this format of a 63x20 char.

```
01-Jan-2015 01:00:00
01-Jan-2015 02:00:00
01-Jan-2015 03:00:00
01-Jan-2015 04:00:00
01-Jan-2015 05:00:00
01-Jan-2015 06:00:00
01-Jan-2015 07:00:00
01-Jan-2015 08:00:00
```

I am simply trying to append data next to these timestamps and write it to a csv file.

Using

```
dlmwrite('test.csv',exportVectorDate{1,3}, 'delimiter','')
```

I am able to write my timestamps into the first column of a csv file. Now, I want to add the associated data with the timestamp on the RIGHT. I have tried

```
dlmwrite('test.csv',averages(:,7),'-append','delimiter',' ','coffset',1)
```

but all this does is append my data to BELOW my timestamps and one space to the right. I have also tried adding 'roffset' and removing '-append' but I just can't get it to work. (Also, I want there to be a comma delimiter between my timestamp and associated value). Thanks

Comment: The `-append` flag **always** appends to the end of the file.  Is it necessary for you to write to the file first and then append to the file after?  Can you write the times **and** the data at the same time?

Comment: @rayryeng is right. You cannot `-append` at an arbitrary row or column offset (Although it may be confusing, this is not what these parameters are for). You have to write each line of your file in one go. Side note, if you want a **coma** delimited file, you have to specify  `'delimiter',','` (_You specified a whitespace in your example_), or just omit this parameter (the default behavior of `dlmwrite` will use coma to separate the values).